# for loop iterated unexpectedly

Tags: for-loop, user-input, inputstream

I am a newbie to Java programming and is trying to self-learn the language. I want to create a program that will terminate when a 's' is typed, but what confuse me is my for loop is iterated twice after a letter is entered?

My code:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws java.io.IOException{

        int i;
        System.out.println("Press s to stop: ");
        for(i = 0; (char) System.in.read() != 's'; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Pass #"+i);
  
            }

    }
```

My result:

[image: result]

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it is because when you press the enter key the `\n` also gets into the inputstream.

Thus one iteration is for the letter the other for the `\n` character.

A Solution would be:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws java.io.IOException{

        int i;
        System.out.println("Press s to stop: ");
        char c = System.in.read();
        for(i = 0;  c != 's'; i++)
            {
                if(c == '\n') continue;
                System.out.println("Pass #"+i);
                c= System.in.read();
            }

    }
```

Comment: Is there anyway to clear off the '\n' in the buffer without reading it?

Comment: Well I do t think you can do that in this way but you can checkout java.io.Console.flush() or you can use scanner as another option